# Numbers Concatenate instead of Adding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that + is used for both addition and concatenation, it depends on what the variable type is. I have tried using Number() and parseFloat(), but I can't seem to get them to work. Here is my code:

```
var grandtotal;         
$("#table tr").each(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var totalprice = row.find('input[id^="TotalPrice"]').val();
    grandtotal += totalprice;
});

$(".total_price").html(grandtotal);
```

This code gives me an output like this:

```
NaN1081083936354412531.5105
```

However, if I add Number() or parseFloat() to the totalprice line like this:

```
grandtotal += Number(totalprice);
```

OR

```
grandtotal += parseFloat(totalprice);
```

I get nothing returned.

Anybody have any idea what I need to change? Thank you.

EDIT: I have changed the controller code to this:

```
 var grandtotal = 0;

            $("#table tr").each(function () {
                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                var totalprice = parseFloat(row.find('input[id^="TotalPrice"]').val());
                grandtotal += totalprice;
            });

            $(".total_price").html(grandtotal);
```

Here is the HTML in question:

```
 <td>
                <div class="input-group">          <div class="input-group-addon">$ </div>
                  <input readonly="readonly" readonly id="TotalPrice{{ $loop->iteration }}" name="TotalPrice[]" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" step="0.01" type="number" value="{{ $item->TotalPrice }}">
                  </div>
            </td>
```

I am still getting a blank output.

Comment: guess it's because the first one returns `NaN` then `grandtotal` is a string. If you want to understand why you get `NaN` then please post your html

Comment: please share the html

Comment: You haven't initialised grandtotal to 0.

Comment: [The global NaN property is a value representing Not-A-Number.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Comment: @braedon _"nothing is returned"_ or "NaN" is returned? Also `grandtotal += +totalprice` is enough. To put it all together...`grandtotal = grandtotal || 0 + +totalprice`.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I think you want to parenthesize `(grandtotal || 0)` because `+` binds more tightly than `||`

Comment: @Pointy definitely yes! tnx

Answer (score 0):

Making `grandtotal` to `0` with `parseFloat()` will solve your problem. You are trying to add `tr` values to undefined variable.

```js
// give grand total a value
var grandtotal = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#table tr").each(function () {
                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                var totalprice = parseFloat(row.find('input[id^="TotalPrice"]').val()); 
                grandtotal += totalprice;
});

 $(".total_price").html(grandtotal);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="table">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="TotalPrice" value="1000.50"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="TotalPrice" value="2000"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="TotalPrice" value="10"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="total_price"></div>
```

Comment: Same time can someone explain `^=` what does this mean ?

Comment: The `^` operator is the bitwise exclusive-OR operator, so `^=` is the assignment version of that (like `+=` except `^` instead of `+`)

Comment: @Pointy thank you for the explanation. Quick learning is much fun. Cheers!

Comment: I know you have this working in a code snippet, so there is definitely something still wrong with my code. I have edited my original question with the updated code and html.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking `isNaN`:

```
// Inside each
if (totalprice && totalprice.length > 0 && !isNaN(totalprice)) {
    grandtotal += parseFloat(totalprice);
}
```

```js
function getFloat(val) {
  if (val && val.length > 0 && !isNaN(val)) {
    return parseFloat(val);
  }
  return null;
}

console.log("getFloat($('#inp1').val()): " + getFloat($('#inp1').val()));
console.log("getFloat($('#inp2').val()): " + getFloat($('#inp2').val()));
console.log("getFloat($('#inp3').val()): " + getFloat($('#inp3').val()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp1" type="text" value="" />
<input id="inp2" type="text" value="literal" />
<input id="inp3" type="text" value="100" />
```

Comment: `.val()` doesn't return `NaN` in any case. Your suggestion won't solve the problem.